# Biblatex without some authors

Tags: biblatex

My aim is not to include my name on the publication list of my CV (as it is fairly clear that I am a coauthor, and hence wastes space).

I had once asked for and gotten a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/cI3Y-tTV7j4).

Rerunning this solution as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{texbook,
    author = {D.E. Knuth},
    title = {The {\TeX}book},
    publisher = {Addison Wesley},
    year = 1986
}

@Book{latexbook,
  author =       "Leslie Lamport",
  title =        "{\LaTeX} - A Document Preparation System - User's Guide and Reference Manual",
  publisher =    {Addison Wesley},
  year =         "1985"
}

@ARTICLE{Demetrescu+Hanck-CauchyCoint:17+,
  author       = {Matei Demetrescu and Christoph Hanck},
  title        = {Multiple Testing for No Cointegration under Nonstationary Volatility},
  year         = {2017+},
  journal      = {Oxford Bulletin},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\DeclareNameFormat{blank}{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{blank}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\newtoggle{ismyself}
\newtoggle{hadmyself}

\NewBibliographyString{with}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  with                = {mit}
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  with                = {with}
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\ifthenelse{\value{author}>1}{\bibstring{with}\addspace}{}}{}%
   % Exclude Yours Truly
   \ifstrequal{#1}{Hanck}{\toggletrue{ismyself}\toggletrue{hadmyself}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}{\togglefalse{hadmyself}}{%
    \iftoggle{ismyself}{}{%
     \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}-1}%
       {\addcomma\addspace}%
       {\iftoggle{hadmyself}{%
          \ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}%
                {\addcomma\addspace}%
                {\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}}
          {\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}}%
     }}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\addspace}%
     \ifblank{#5}{}{#5\addspace}%
     \togglefalse{ismyself}%
     #1%
     \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}%
   \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}\AND\value{author}>1}{\unspace}{}%
}


\begin{document}
\cite{texbook} \cite{Demetrescu+Hanck-CauchyCoint:17+}
\end{document}
```

now produces [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348783/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-blxdefformatd-ifblank3) error message, apparently related to an update of biblatex.

Would anybody know how to tweak the link of the first solution to the new version of biblatex?

Comment: Not a real answer to this question, but maybe an alternative solution: Do you know the [`biblatex-publist` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist?lang=en)? It may do what you want. Especially, it removes _your_ name from the author list but leaves in everybody elses, which may be more correct than just not giving any author information at all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Actually, my previous solution only removed my name, too, I was maybe not clear there.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Do you want to write that up in an answer? `biblatex-publist` is definitely a good choice for lists of publications on CVs. And it works around having to code a solution on one's own.

Answer (score 2):

The [`biblatex-publist`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist) package is a dedicated style for CVs. You can give your name in the `\plauthorname` command, your name will then be filtered out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=publist]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\plauthorname[Emma]{Sigfridsson}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]